# Is database deletion through Entity Framework permanent?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a web application using EntityFramework and an Azure SQL Database. I would like to know if deleting a row in the database removes the information permanently or simply marks is as deleted but it still be accessed if needed?

```
db.MyTable.Remove(objectInstance);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is this someting that can be configured or do I need to implement this feature myself adding a `deleted` attribute?

The reason I want this is to be able to perform analytics including objects that might have been already deleted

Comment: Hmm you always got your sql log file which is used for rollbacks and recovery, the data is saved there as well. why are u asking tho?

Comment: I added my reason to the question. According to what you are saying it seems to me better to make my implementation because retrieving the data from the log files seem like extra complication

Comment: Yes, as far as your database is concerned the data is permanently deleted.  If you want to implement your way of marking it as deleted add a new column to your database table called `Deleted` for example and have a bool value of 0 or 1 or -1

Comment: I never attempted to get the data from there, and I don't think you should either, it wasn't built for that reason.
If I was you I would implement it myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF has nothing to do with this actually. Whether records are deleted permanently or not is actually up to the RDBMS. EF is an ORM for the RDBMS.

Options IMO:

1. You manage the records marked as deleted using an extra column
2. You can move the deleted records to another table or file whichever is convenient for you to run analytics on. That way your queries will have to touch less number of records and be faster.
3. You can go through the log files and execute the INSERTs again to get the deleted records.

Hope my suggestions help you in right direction.

Comment: Option 2 seems best. Thanks. By the way I mentioned EF to include the context of my implementation in case that was somehow relevant.